# Apache fop font-size

Tags: apache-fop

I need to create report using Apache-FOP, I want that report in different font-sizes such as (10pts,20pts) , so is that possible to give font size as input in xsl template? Please if you have any suggestions please post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:attribute name="font-size">24pt</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="font-family">Helvetica</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="color">#848587</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="font-weight">Light</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Koray, It helped me a little bit, but i wanted solution for giving input for font size from java class to XSL template.